# Suspend seems to just turn off laptop

Tags: suspend, power-management, 19.10

When I shut the lid of my laptop, it looks like it suspeds, but then when I open it up it automatically turns on, but starts a full normal boot process instead of resuming.

This in `journalctl` logs may be helpful

```
Mar 09 17:15:22 meowko kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.HEC.CHRG], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190703/psargs-330)
Mar 09 17:15:22 meowko kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [PNOT]
Mar 09 17:15:22 meowko kernel: No Arguments are initialized for method [PNOT]
Mar 09 17:15:22 meowko kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \PNOT due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190703/psparse-529)
Mar 09 17:15:22 meowko kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.AC._PSR due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190703/psparse-529)
Mar 09 17:15:22 meowko kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, Error reading AC Adapter state (20190703/ac-115)
...
Mar 09 17:15:40 meowko systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Mar 09 17:15:40 meowko systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Mar 09 17:15:40 meowko systemd-sleep[31358]: Suspending system...
Mar 09 17:15:40 meowko kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
```

There's nothing I can see in the boot logs - it just looks like a normal from cold boot.

Other [posts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/443405/23542) seem to suggest that those ACPI errors are nothing to worry about.

The laptop used to suspend/resume OK. I *think* it might have stopped working shortly after installing `cpufrequtils` (and possibly related packages) when I tried a gnome shell extension or two to extend battery life. I've since uninstalled those ([1](http://konkor.github.io/cpufreq/install/#uninstalling))  but the behaviour persists.

Comment: I see same since kernel upgrade. output from 'uname -a' says kernel version '5.3.0-40-generic #32'. I'm going to remove that one and hope for best in future.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to get things working again

- Disable C-States and Intel SpeedStep in BIOS settings
- reboot, test: suspend works.
- Re-enable C-States and SpeedStep in BIOS
- reboot, test: all works again.

(I'm on `Linux meowko 5.3.0-40-generic #32`)

### What I think went wrong: Advice for others.

In an attempt to make my battery last longer, I had installed [cpufreq gnome extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1082/cpufreq/) and also the `cpufrequtils` package.

It turns out that using that to reduce the number of online processors, if you have `irqbalance` installed (which I did), can really mess up your system. I've [suggested](https://github.com/konkor/cpufreq/issues/138) that they change their UI to disallow this as it seems a bit of a foot-gun.

So the full list of what I did to fix this was:

1. use the extension to ensure all cores were ON
2. uninstall the extension (there's a manual process for that)
3. uninstall cpufreq*
4. do the above.

I then uninstalled irqbalance - opinion seems mixed about whether this is a good thing: lots of advice says "only for servers", but the package itself says good for multi processor SMP systems (I have 8 cores in my laptop). So I'm lost there.

Anyway, I uninstalled irqbalance, reinstalled the extension which seemed to work better this time. However whenever I put some cores offline the system got hot, was working at 40W (normally c20W), so I concluded that was not a good way to save power/battery, and uninstalled everything again. I've left irqbalance uninstalled for now.

Comment: Puzzling to me. My system quit suspending with the kernel update and problem solved with downgrade.  I have none of the packages you are concerned about.  I suspect there is more in the story. Puzzling that more users don't report trouble.